# How to update custom field data in product custom option by csv in magento?

Tags: magento, magmi

I hope someone can help me with this as it is driving me crazy!
I add weight column filed in my custom field by fellow that link:- 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/73036/

Now I want to upload custom option values by csv , i used magmi for that, my csv file data is :-

```
sku,Size:drop_down:1:0
060-SKdaily,1 oz. bottle:fixed:14.9500:0.120:0:0|5 ml. sample:fixed:2.7500:0.020:2:2
```

but it not update weight filed 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Magmi does not support the import of data for 3rd party customizations.

Since you've modified Magento to include weight on custom options, you will also need to write a Magmi plugin to import the weight values for custom options.

Comment: Can you please tell me the whole process ? How can i create plugin in magmi ?

Comment: @user3630977 did you figure it out ?